Can you add new bake on to an existing texture in Blender?
I am baking diffuse map for multiple objects on one texture. Lets say texture for two objects is already baked, and I need to add bake of a third object on this already existing texture. Can you do that in blender without re-baking textures for all three objects again?
I know I could just bake the third one separately and then join two images into one, but I'm just wondering if you can do something like that in Blender to save time

Yes, you can. For this to work, Clear Image in the Bake panel should be unchecked. This means that new bakes will only write to the pixels corresponding to the selected objects' UV maps.

